# Variable Bar Inputs/Outputs not configurable in HTML5 version

Tags: flowgear

The 'Manage Variables' option is not available or is inaccessible in the HTML5 version of flowgear.
https://developers.flowgear.net/kb/Node:Variable_Bar

^ It says to right click the Node Header and choose 'Manage Variables' but right clicking the Node does not do anything. The only option available when clicking the gear icon on then node is the option to delete it and the option to check help which links to the page above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new console, click the plus icon below the properties to add properties. Not all features of variable management are migrated to the new console yet so you may want to use the legacy one if you need to set variable types.

Comment: Where do I download the legacy version? (the portable Silverlight version)

Comment: After opening a workflow from the workflow list, hover over the info icon next to the design button. The tooltip lists features that aren't yet migrated and provides a link to the legacy console